# Select entries from table B with multiple conditions from table A

Tags: mysql, database

I've been trying to wrap my brain around this using joins, subquery joins, not exists clauses and I keep failing to come up with a query that produces the correct results.

Table A - PRIMARY id (irrelevant for this issue)

```
id | campaign_id | user_id
--------------------------
1         1           1
2         1           2
3         0           3
4         2           3
5         1           2
```

Table B - UNIQUE campaign_id+user_id

```
campaign_id | user_id | admin
-----------------------------
     1           1        1
     1           2        0
     1           3        0
     2           3        0
```

What I need to do is find instances of Table B where the user no longer has an entry in Table A that correspond with the campaign_id in Table B. Table A is the main content and they can have multiple entries of Table A that are present in the campaign. Table B is a member table that indicates they're a member of the campaign and whether they're an admin or not. In addition, they could have in entry in Table B as admin, but not have an entry in Table A, so the query must check for admin=0.

In the example entries, the invalid entry in Table B would be campaign_id 1, user_id 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an outer join and then state in the `where` clause that the outer joined table's `user_id` is null:

```
select    tblB.*
from      tblB
left join tblA 
       on tblA.campaign_id = tblB.campaign_id
      and tblA.user_id = tblB.user_id
where     tblB.admin = 0
      and tblA.user_id is null
```

Comment: Yep that did it. I knew I could do it with a join with the 2 conditionals, I think I forgot the user_id is null. Thanks for the fast answer!